# Where in the American West Would a New City Arise?

Tags: post-apocalypse, geography, cities, deserts

It's been 20 years since a global pandemic wiped out over 99% of the world population, and America was not spared. Of the 330 million people in the country (give or take a few million), only about 1.5 million remained one year after the start of the plague. Assume roughly 1 million of these reside in the Eastern U.S, and that Canada and Mexico were similarly affected.

People are beginning to rebuild. With the plague gone (people were too few and far between for too long), they can begin to live in large communities again. Lots of these would develop, but I'm looking for a big one in the American West to center my story on: think New Los Angeles (or, y'know, New Vegas).

Considering geography, but also surviving infrastructure, population distribution (urban areas were hit harder and earlier, so let's say it's roughly uniform for the sake of simplicity), and any other relevant factors, where would this city appear?

Don't worry about the fact that the Eastern U.S has a better climate, there's going to be a city there too, but that isn't relevant. Also, I can't imagine people  would just move into empty metropolises like Los Angeles or San Francisco (sure, the resources are great, but would wants to live in a skyscraper where every apartment except for yours in full of dead bodies?) This is a new settlement, or at least a small one that has been reconstructed and expanded post-pandemic. Bonus points if you can name a spot within California, Nevada, Arizona, or New Mexico.

Possible ideas I had already include:

- [Tulare Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulare_Lake), which, if I understand correctly, would refill to a certain extent after 2 decades of no (large-scale) agriculture in the region.
- Lake Tahoe
- Somewhere along the Gulf of California (possibly at the mouth of a river)
- Along one of the rivers in Northern California (such as the [Smith River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_River_(California)))
- On the Rio Grande, upstream from Albuquerque
- On the Colorado River, wherever there's decent soil.

Comment: As you yourself have shown this question has many valid answers. Such questions are considered too broad for this site.

Comment: It seems counterintuitive that 2/3 of the American survivors _of a plague_  are on the East coast, with just a half-million people across practically the rest of the continent. A deadly, contagious disease would create exactly the opposite result: decimating dense population centers (i.e. both coasts) while isolated people survive.

Comment: I wasn't too deliberate in picking my numbers, but by "Eastern U.S.", I meant east of the Mississippi, not the Eastern Seaboard. There's a lot of rural territory, clean water sources, hospitable climates, and fertile farmland in places like Appalachia and the Midwest.

Comment: Robbie, for the record, the [help/dont-ask] specifically states that to avoid having your question closed, do NOT include your answers and expect more answers. The basic problem is this: you have already answered your question, so why should we answer it? Just looking for more options violates the [help/on-topic]'s prohibition against brainstorming. As written, your question should be closed. Now, if you have specific reasons why those answers don't work for you, you should list those reasons... but not your answers that you don't want us to consider.

Comment: Having said all that, 80% of the U.S. population lives in the eastern half of the nation. Only 20% lives in the western half. Why isn't important. What's important is that you could reasonably build communities almost anywhere. Not communities like L.A. or Las Vegas, you don't have enough people to do that, anyway. With only 1.5M in the U.S. and a big city in the East you only have a max of 750K population to work with and they're spread out all over. But any river or lake will provide the needed water. And suddenly there's a lot of it.. There are locations in every western state.

Comment: Finally, I think you're reasoning behind not using existing cities is... well... it's wrong. Those cities represent VAST resources. Food, equipment, fuel, even raw materials. Unless there's something about those dead bodies that keep everyone away, they'll be living near if not in the cities for absolutely obvious reasons. And a year or two after the event, most of the bodies will have mummified (dehydrated) enough that it's no longer important. There will be bodies everywhere. Your people will quickly grow accustomed to it.

Comment: @JBH Okay, I wasn't aware of the ban on brainstorming questions. I'll keep that in mind in the future (in retrospect, I realize there's a few things I could have done to improve the quest). And, of course, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Your 20 years is too short of a time before people will start to move back into cities. This 99% mortality is partly due to the plague itself. The rest is from starvation and other disease as the cities don't get food or clean water. It is more likely to take 200-300 years to recover enough to build cities. (For example, see how long it took to build back up the population in the Mississippi river basin after the similar 95% mortality in the 1500's.)

All this time, people are trying to scratch out a living - learning how to grow crops, how to forage for wild foods, and learning how to butcher the game they killed. The problems that the survivors will have run into include how the infrastructure that they use to rely upon no longer works. Most importantly, the energy sources upon all the rest of civilization was built upon no longer work. Farming without diesel fuel, nitrogen fertilizer, mass markets like chain restaurants, and seed and supplier companies will be very different.

But, where in the west could a town develop? Look first to water supplies without using high tech supply systems. (They won't work anymore.) Over time, the major rivers (Columbia, Sacramento, Colorado, etc.) will have broken through most of the dams we have placed on them, and the survivors will build based on free-flowing water. Places such as near Sacramento CA and Portland OR will have enough water. The Colorado river will provide water to places near its mouth on the Gulf of California, but it is in a deep canyon for most of its length which will prevent farming or a city anywhere else. Phoenix AZ has water canals that predate Europeans and can build a city. The Rio Grande can build a small town based on pre-European water management systems.

Comment: Oh, make no mistake, this "city" is going to be in rough shape, and will likely resemble a refugee camp more than an actual city. The idea, however, is there's enough resources left over for people to scavenge until they figure out how to establish small farms and homesteads. It would be rough for a while, but a lot of people would make it. From there, I find it easy to imagine how larger settlements (like towns of under 5000 people) could redevelop within a few decades.

Comment: @Robbie Your "refugee camp" will exist only till everyone dies of starvation or go out to where they can find food. (We only have refugee camps today because we force refugees to live in camps.) Towns are a "luxury". Towns exist because of enough population in an area and enough spare food is produced to allow some folks to specialize in trade.  When everyone is scrambling to find food, nobody will live in a town.

Answer (score 2):

I can at least offer one group, that being my own. If you like New Vegas, think of the New Canaanites. My ancestors in early Utah had an extremely arid landscape that they were able to make into one of the few urban centers in the great basin. In a place no one wanted, they made a home.

In any apocalypse, I am quite sure a lot of us would survive. Latter-day Saints are encouraged to store food, and do other sensible preparations for difficult times.

So I'm not sure if a Latter-day Saint or Utah based community would be what you'd want to focus your story on, but for your background worldbuilding, know that it would be there.

My only caution to you is that if you choose to feature people of our faith in your story, you pay heed not fall into exoticism - we are not some crazy foreign people, but just normal people living out there lives, trying to make it like everyone else. You'd want to make sure for any time you talk about this that you try to do some more than surface level research, as you have the potential to offend members of our church otherwise.

Last point, we have members everywhere. In disaster scenarios today, we organize relief efforts. We keep community food storage and have things like cattle ranches meant just for charity efforts. Any time there is a hurricane people with the "helping hands" shirts go out to help.

So sorry to be doing a bit of grandstanding about my own background, but it is what I know, and it might make for some amount of worldbuilding in your story, to mention how just another group of people deal with a post apocalypse.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the Mormons! Religion is going to be a critical element of my story, and it would be interesting to consider what a post-apocalyptic Mormon Utah would look like. Thank you for sharing your background (truly, I appreciate being able to draw on present-day culture and real experiences), and I promise I'll be careful when dealing with the topic.

Comment: @Robbie First thing to understand xD Sorry if I get nitpicky with this - I'd expect the culture of the church to change, and how the doctrine is taught in some ways, but many things will stay the same (as a big belief of ours is that Christ's church was lost in apostasy, so we care about maintaining doctrine. Anyway...

"Mormon" is an incorrect nickname. It's real name is The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, church members being referred to as Latter-day Saints. Members of the church care about this as it identifies our main belief. I'd expect though like today, people would (1/2

Comment: @wasatch wind ... still call us "mormons" or "LDS" or even some other name. New Caananites in New Vegas is an interesting one.

Comment: Okay, I hope my ignorance didn't offend, being religious myself I understand how it feels when people misunderstand. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Robbie no, not at all. Being called mormons is something we do not like, but if you get a bunch of other things right I think many people would appreciate it. Sadly I have not seen a depiction of our church put in a really good light. The new canaanites in New Vegas were inoffensive, but a bit surface level. Stuff like the expanse though legitimately makes me feel uncomfortable with how it treats us as some exotic group of people. That I do not like. We are different from others, but only to an extent.

Answer (score 2):

**Camp Pendleton**

[image: camp pendleton]

The military based at Camp Pendelton kept order during the plague.  It also kept the nuclear power plant at NRG Cabrillo running, and running at 5% capacity the nuclear fuel stored on site will last 50 years.  The nuclear plant has a desalinator and with fresh water the flower fields of Oceanside and Carlsbad can easily be converted to grow food in the mild SoCal climate.